# What is a view_closure in range-v3?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

In a case like this:

```
auto pow = [](int i) {return i * i; };
auto closure = ranges::views::transform(pow);
```

`closure` seems to be a `view_closure`. I do get that last line does not make much sense, since transform is not applied anywhere. *Actually, I could may as well pipe a vector `x` into `closure` and it would both compile and work properly*.

But, what **is** a view closure? Is it a "function like" object that expects to be applied somewhere? What are its semantics?

I found [this](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/1120609c7cb5dee9d2d216c579e935475cc39c4e/include/range/v3/view/view.hpp#L168-L178) from Eric Niebler's `range-v3` source code but there aren't any docs specifying it elsewhere.

I don't even get whether `view_closure` is intended for internal usage or for the users' end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `view_closure` class template in range-v3 that is an implementation strategy for what in C++20 became the [range adaptor closure object](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptor.object) concept:

> A *range adaptor closure object* is a unary function object that accepts a `viewable_range` argument and returns a `view`. For a range adaptor closure object `C` and an expression `R` such that `decltype((R))` models `viewable_­range`, the following expressions are equivalent and yield a view:
>
> ```
> C(R)
> R | C
> ```
>
> Given an additional range adaptor closure object `D`, the expression `C | D` is well-formed and produces another range adaptor closure object such that the following two expressions are equivalent:
>
> ```
> R | C | D
> R | (C | D)
> ```

The result of `transform(f)` is a range adaptor closure object, which you can apply to a `viewable_range` either via pipe as `r | transform(f)` or via call as `transform(f)(r)`, either of which will give you some kind of `transform_view` adaptor.

More broadly, `transform` itself is a *range adaptor object* which is defined in a way such that `transform(f)` gives you a range adaptor closure object such that `transform(r, f)`, `r | transform(f)`, and `transform(f)(r)` are all equivalent.

`view_closure`, the class template, is necessary to ensure that stuff like this works:

```cpp
auto adaptor = transform(f) | filter(g) | chunks(n);
```

That is, you can build up a pipeline without having a range, and the result of that is a range adaptor closure object that you can then apply to a range - `r | adaptor` would be equivalent to `r | transform(f) | filter(g) | chunks(n)` which is equivalent to `chunks(filter(transform(r, f), g), n)`.

That class template basically affects what `operator|` does, among other things. You only need to use it if you're creating your own range adaptor, it's not something you need to care about as a user of ranges otherwise.

Comment: I think you are verifying my point. Your answer is great! Thanks a ton! I needed the Standard insight you gave :)

Answer (score 2):

`view_closure` is not a *type*, it is a template. The exact type of that expression is an instantiation of that template with an unnamed closure type (i.e. `decltype(pow)`). It is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks. Bad phrasing from my side. I guess then the question then becomes: What types and requirements does this template implement?

Comment: @giannisgonidelis iirc it can be the right hand side of `operator|`, resulting in a range object that when traversed applies the transform to the elements of the range it was `|`ed.